# How to change position on input in a form when windows is resized?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

As you can see from this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sappe/y6ka1oz5/).

```
<input>
```

in jsFiddle elements are "fluid": if you resize the window the inputs will change position and start going after the previous input.

How can I achieve the same result? With bootstrap? I'm actually using jquery ui.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you always want the inputs in one line/row when resizing?

Comment: No, I want them to go one under another when resized

Comment: Still struggling to understand. Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y6ka1oz5/1/ when resising, they currently do all fall under each other. Or do you want it to read like this. Column 1 1&4, Column 2 2&5, column 3 3&6.

Comment: As they are currently doing, falling one under the previous one

Comment: But that is exactly what it is currently happening. Or do you want them one under the other from the start. Apologies, just struggling to figure out exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This is working in jsFiddle, I want to know how they did it, since my form it's not doing it... Don't know if I explained myself.

Comment: I tried to enable the chat as I'm trying to avoid a conversation in the comments. From what I understand is the elements in jsfiddle are doing what you want. That tells me that the containers on your form isn't allowing for this to happen. You could perhaps have two columns floating next to each other and when resizing the float breaks and puts the two containers underneath each other. You can fix this by grouping the matching inputs in to the same container and then floating them. When resizing they'll fall underneath each other. Hope I understood correctly and that this makes sense.

Comment: You do not need Boostrap to do that, folk. Just learn how to use flexbox, build a good HTML structure and responsive design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same functionality using bootstrap grid system.
It is responsive, and the columns will re-arrange automatically depending on the screen size. It allows up to 12 columns across the page.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp) on bootstrap grid system.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may have to use bootstrap.css something like [this](http://www.bootply.com/slkJpZk5P9).

Comment: I have to study this solution, since is not very applicable to my case, but thank you for the suggestion